# Expected value in a dice roll game

Tags: probability, expected-value, game-theory, puzzle, dice

""Roll a die, and you get paid what the dice shows. But if you want, you can request a second chance & roll the die again; get paid what the second roll shows instead of the first. What is the expected value"" 
This question has been asked many times. But my question is whats wrong with my reasoning. 
So a normal approach goes like this: Expected value on the first dice roll is $3.5$. Now if you get $4,5,6>3.5$, don't re-roll. Else, re-roll.
So this gives, $Exp.=(\frac36)(5)+(\frac36)(3.5)=4.25$. 
 
Now my reasoning is just a bit different. Let the expected value of the whole game be $x$. Now if I play the game infinite times, I would expect to win $x$ out of it. So if on the first roll, I don't get at least $x$, then I would re-roll. (**This was the difference**). 
Using this logic gives the equation (assuming $x$ to be a real number not an integer but a fraction): $$x=\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{6}(3.5)+\frac{6-\lfloor x\rfloor}{6}(\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor+1+6}{2})$$
This equation holds true for $x=\frac{25}{6}\approx4.1667$. 
So what is wrong with my approach? 
 
**Edit:**
Looking back at the problem it seems that the question is missing one piece of information, and that is *when* does the player decide to re-roll. So assuming that threshold to be $k$, the expected value becomes:
$$\frac{\lfloor k\rfloor}{6}(3.5)+\frac{6-\lfloor k\rfloor}{6}(\frac{\lfloor k \rfloor+1+6}{2})$$
which attains maximum at $\lfloor k\rfloor=3$. So this means that the question basically *assumes* that the player would take a step which basically maximises the total expected value.

Comment: It's not as if you get to restart the game if your initial toss is $<x$, rather you are just declaring you will accept the result of the second toss.

Comment: @lulu, haven't I taken that into account in the first term on the RHS? $3.5$ term.

Comment: I don't see how.  You invented a new strategy for playing the game, but yours is sub-optimal.

Comment: @lulu, that's true. So why does the first strategy give the optimal solution?

Comment: All strategies for the game have the same form:  Pick a cut off $N$.  Keep the first toss iff it exceeds $N$.  It is a simple matter to figure out the expected value of the $N-$strategy, then take the max of those.

Comment: @lulu, yes. Exactly!! That's what I just added in an edit also. Any reason why would the first strategy give this N=3?

Comment: Of course.  The expected value of the second toss is $3.5$  If you already have a $4$ then you expect the second toss to hurt you so why do it?

Comment: @lulu, oh. That makes a lot of sense. We judge our threshold using the expected value of the remaining game! That makes sense. Thanks!